# Add count column to Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a Pandas data frame that keeps data for checkouts of laptops in my department. The dataframe has columns for time checked out (column name `Out`), time checked in (`In`), the name of the person checking out (`Name`), and the number of machines checked out by that person (`Number`). I want to create a new dataframe that shows both the number of times checkouts occurred in a given week, and the number of machines checked out in a given week. The original data frame is called `cb`.

I was able to make a pivot table that gets me the number of machines checked out by week:

```
dates = pd.pivot_table(cb, values="Number", index="Out",  aggfunc=sum)
```

I'm wondering what I can add to this line of code to add a new column that calculates the number of times machines were checked out. For example if two people checked out laptops in a given week, person 1 checked out 10 laptops, and person 2 checked out 5, then there should be a "Number" column that reads "15" for this week and another column "Frequency" that reads "2".

Is this possible with a single `pivot_table` line or is there more to it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here's what I hope is a small example of what I am looking for. First, here's raw data from the CSV I am reading:

```
Name    Number  DateOut TimeOut DateIn  TimeIn
C   1   8/31/2017   2:00p   9/1/2017    3:40p
Ma  2   8/31/2017   3:30p   .   .
S   1   9/6/2017    10:50a  9/6/2017    1:55p
S   3   9/7/2017    10:00a  9/7/2017    3:00p
C   1   9/7/2017    2:20p   9/8/2017    11:00a
Ma  2   9/7/2017    4:00p   9/8/2017    10:00a
S   4   9/8/2017    10:50a  9/8/2017    3:15p
W   6   9/11/2017   8:15a   9/11/2017   11:00a
B   4   9/11/2017   10:45a  9/11/2017   1:00p
S   4   9/11/2017   10:55a  9/11/2017   3:55p
S   3   9/12/2017   12:55p  9/12/2017   3:00p
Ma  2   9/12/2017   4:00p   9/15/2017   10:00a
S   1   9/13/2017   11:00a  9/13/2017   1:00p
T   1   9/13/2017   1:00p   .   .
K   1   9/13/2017   2:00p   9/14/2017   10:00a
F   2   9/13/2017   4:00p   9/14/2017   11:45a
S   3   9/14/2017   1:00p   9/14/2017   3:00p
C   1   9/14/2017   3:50p   9/15/2017   10:00a
F   4   9/15/2017   9:35a   9/15/2017   3:00p
```

(Names redacted for privacy.)

The code for reading it in (parsing the given dates into a correct DateTime index):

```
import pandas as pd
cb = pd.read_csv("chromebookdata.csv", na_values=".", 
             parse_dates={"In": [2,3], "Out":[4,5]})
cb['In'] = pd.to_datetime(cb['In'], errors="coerce")
cb['Out'] = pd.to_datetime(cb['Out'], errors="coerce")
```

Creating a pivot table that gives the number of machines each week:

```
dates = pd.pivot_table(cb, values="Number", index="Out",  aggfunc=sum)
dates_weekly = dates.resample("W").sum()
```

This pivot table gives me the number of machines checked out per week:

```
            Number
In                
2017-09-03     3.0
2017-09-10    11.0
2017-09-17    33.0
```

What I want is a new column for the number of *times* checkouts occurred, so for these data it would look like:

```
            Number    Count
In                
2017-09-03     3.0        2
2017-09-10    11.0        5
2017-09-17    33.0       12
```

Comment: Throws an error "Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'".

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with some sample data and the expected output? It's difficult to visualize what should be going on with words alone.

Comment: Added above, I hope that's sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `dates_weekly` and `cb` dataframes are sorted by date:

```
# Round your dates to the day
cb['dates'] = cb['dates'].dt.floor('d') 
# Group by rounded date and count the number of rows per each date
dates_weekly['frequency'] = cb.groupby('dates').agg('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list in the aggfunction. Try `aggfunc=['sum', 'count']` when you create the pivot table